# How can i change the colour of the font of whole web page using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to change font colour using JavaScript of a web page, I've made a button in my html code, after pressing that button i want my font to change it's colour. Any ideas?

Comment: Please include your HTML in the question along with the JS you've written in an attempt to achieve your goal.

Comment: Set a color style definition on the body:  document.body.style.color = [color-value];

Answer (score -1):

I suggest to swap files upon that button click (using JS) to the other CSS file where the font color has changed but with same content.